# WebStorm Code Completion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webstorm

I am using [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) and at `app/index.html`  I don't have code completion for Bootstrap classes.

In settings WebStorm recognises the Bootstrap dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `settings/languages&frameworks/javascript/libraries/`. Click on `download`, select `typescript community stubs` and install bootstrap from the list. If this does not work, then probably you should report the issue I guess to the author of the typescript lib.

By your own objects/classes you can use e.g. jsdoc3 to enable auto completion if webstorm does not understand them. Probably there are other solutions in the topic, but I don't know them.

off:

*Ez van, amikor két magyar megbeszéli a neten angolul, hogy mit kéne csinálni.*

Comment: Thanks, i found these `typescript community stubs` when i was looking for `express.js` code completion and also found bootstrap there. :)

off: teljesen jo :)